# DD4T 2 Java Spring MVC web application "PageController" issue

Tags: content-delivery, dd4t

I have created a bare DD4T 2 Java Spring MVC web application based on the DD4T Archetype by using following Maven archetype.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=mywebapp -DarchetypeGroupId=org.dd4t -DarchetypeArtifactId=dd4t-spring-mvc-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.5  -DarchetypeCatalog=remote -DarchetypeCatalog=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
```

[image]

Then I configured `cd_storage_conf.xml`, `logback.xml`, `dd4t.properties` and `cd_dynamic.conf.xml` as per DD4T quick-start instructions.

## cd_storage_conf.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="6.1" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../schemas/cd_storage_conf.xsd">
    <Global>
        <ObjectCache Enabled="true">
            <Policy Type="LRU" Class="com.tridion.cache.LRUPolicy">
                <Param Name="MemSize" Value="32mb"/>
            </Policy>    
            <Features>
                <Feature Type="DependencyTracker" Class="com.tridion.cache.DependencyTracker"/>
            </Features>
        </ObjectCache>    
        <Storages>
            <Storage Type="persistence" Id="defaultdb" dialect="MSSQL" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">
                <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="10" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120"/>
                <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                    <Property Name="serverName" Value="localhost"/>
                    <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433"/>
                    <Property Name="databaseName" Value="SDLWeb_broker_sample"/>
                    <Property Name="user" Value="BrokerUser"/>
                    <Property Name="password" Value="*******"/>
                </DataSource>
            </Storage>
        </Storages>
    </Global>    
    <ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="true"/>
</Configuration>
```

## logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true">
    <!-- Properties -->
    <property name="log.pattern" value="%date %-5level %logger{0} - %message%n"/>
    <property name="log.history" value="1"/>
    <property name="log.folder" value="/var/dd4t"/>
    <property name="log.level" value="DEBUG"/>
```

## dd4t.properties

```
# dd4t.properties

# Publication resolving
publication.resolving.use.cd.dynamic=true

# View Models
databind.viewmodels.rootpackage=com.example.models
databind.viewmodels.ct.metadata.viewnamekey=view

# XPM
xpm.enabled=false
xpm.cmsUrl=http://localhost:81/

# Caching
monitor.service.interval=30000

#cache expired elements for amount of seconds
cache.expired.ttl=299
cache.dependency.ttl=299
cache.ttl=3599

# JMS caching.
# jms.brokerUrl=tcp://localhost:61616?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=60000
# jms.userName=admin
# jms.password=admin
# jms.topicName=TridionCCS
```

## cd_dynamic_conf.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="6.1" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../schemas/cd_dynamic_conf.xsd">
         <URLMappings>
             <StaticMappings>
                 <Publications>
                     <Publication Id="5">
                         <Host Domain="localhost" Port="85" Protocol="http" Path="C:\visitorsweb" />
                     </Publication>
                 </Publications>
             </StaticMappings>
             <StorageMapping IdentifyPublicationByProperty="publicationUrl"/>
         </URLMappings>
     </Configuration>
```

it got built successfully.

[image]

When I am running the project system is throwing "BeanCreationException" for "pageController".

**Tomcat log is as following:**

```
<Start>INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 25, 2016 10:43:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.35
May 25, 2016 10:44:00 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [102] milliseconds.
May 25, 2016 10:44:07 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
May 25, 2016 10:44:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
May 25, 2016 10:44:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2016-05-25 22:44:08,334 INFO  ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
2016-05-25 22:44:08,508 INFO  XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed May 25 22:44:08 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-05-25 22:44:08,617 INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [dispatcher-servlet.xml]
2016-05-25 22:44:08,787 INFO  ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
2016-05-25 22:44:09,222 INFO  PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from class path resource [WEB-INF/classes/dd4t.properties]
2016-05-25 22:44:09,256 INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7ebdbcf: defining beans [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,pageController,componentPresentationController,binaryController,viewResolver,publicationResolver,propertiesService,publicationResolverFactory,linkResolverProcessor,cacheProvider,binaryProvider,componentPresentationProvider,pageProvider,linkProvider,publicationProvider,linkResolver,pageFactory,componentPresentationFactory,binaryFactory,serializer,serializerFactory,taxonomyProvider,taxonomyFactory,modelConverter,dataBinder,databindFactory,xpmRender]; root of factory hierarchy
2016-05-25 22:44:09,275 INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7ebdbcf: defining beans [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,pageController,componentPresentationController,binaryController,viewResolver,publicationResolver,propertiesService,publicationResolverFactory,linkResolverProcessor,cacheProvider,binaryProvider,componentPresentationProvider,pageProvider,linkProvider,publicationProvider,linkResolver,pageFactory,componentPresentationFactory,binaryFactory,serializer,serializerFactory,taxonomyProvider,taxonomyFactory,modelConverter,dataBinder,databindFactory,xpmRender]; root of factory hierarchy
2016-05-25 22:44:09,286 ERROR ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pageController' defined in class path resource [dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'publicationResolver' while setting bean property 'publicationResolver'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'publicationResolver' defined in class path resource [dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'publicationProvider' while setting bean property 'publicationProvider'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'publicationProvider' defined in class path resource [dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/tridion/DeliveryException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) ~[spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) ~[spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383) ~[spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283) ~[spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4813) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5272) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'publicationResolver' defined in class path resource [dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'publicationProvider' while setting bean property 'publicationProvider'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'publicationProvider' defined in class path resource [dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/tridion/DeliveryException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'publicationProvider' defined in class path resource [dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/tridion/DeliveryException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1011) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:957) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/tridion/DeliveryException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2503) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:831) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1274) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.35]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:78) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1004) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tridion.DeliveryException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.35]
    ... 55 common frames omitted
<End>
```

Here is my spring `dispatcher-servlet.xml` file for bean configuration cross check.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd">    
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list merge="true">
                <value>classpath:WEB-INF/classes/dd4t.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    </bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.controllers" annotation-config="false"/>
    <bean id="pageController" class="com.example.controllers.PageController">
        <property name="pageViewPath" value="pages/"/>
        <property name="publicationResolver" ref="publicationResolver" />
        <property name="pageFactory" ref="pageFactory"/>
    </bean>    
    <bean id="componentPresentationController" class="com.example.controllers.ComponentPresentationController">
        <property name="componentViewPath" value="components/"/>
    </bean>    
    <bean id="binaryController" class="com.example.controllers.BinaryController">
        <property name="binaryRootFolder" value="/media"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="publicationResolver" class="org.dd4t.core.resolvers.impl.UrlPublicationResolver">
        <property name="publicationProvider" ref="publicationProvider" />
        <property name="useCdDynamic" value="${publication.resolving.use.cd.dynamic}" />
    </bean>    
    <bean id="propertiesService" class="org.dd4t.mvc.utils.PropertiesServiceImpl">
        <property name="location" value="dd4t.properties"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="publicationResolverFactory" factory-method="getInstance" class="org.dd4t.mvc.utils.PublicationResolverFactory">
        <property name="publicationResolver" ref="publicationResolver" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="linkResolverProcessor"
          class="org.dd4t.core.processors.impl.LinkingProcessor">
        <property name="runPhase" value="AFTER_CACHING" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="cacheProvider" class="org.dd4t.providers.impl.NoCacheProvider" />    
    <bean id="binaryProvider" class="org.dd4t.providers.impl.BrokerBinaryProvider">
        <property name="contentIsCompressed" value="true"/>
        <property name="cacheProvider" ref="cacheProvider" />
    </bean>  
    <bean id="componentPresentationProvider" class="org.dd4t.providers.impl.BrokerComponentPresentationProvider">
        <property name="contentIsCompressed" value="true"/>
        <property name="concreteComponentPresentation" value="org.dd4t.contentmodel.impl.ComponentPresentationImpl" />
        <property name="concreteComponentTemplateImpl" value="org.dd4t.contentmodel.impl.ComponentTemplateImpl" />
        <property name="cacheProvider" ref="cacheProvider" />
    </bean>    
    <bean id="pageProvider" class="org.dd4t.providers.impl.BrokerPageProvider">
        <property name="contentIsCompressed" value="true"/>
        <property name="cacheProvider" ref="cacheProvider" />
    </bean>    
    <bean id="linkProvider" class="org.dd4t.providers.impl.BrokerLinkProvider">
        <property name="contentIsCompressed" value="true"/>
    </bean>    
    <bean id="publicationProvider" class="org.dd4t.providers.impl.BrokerPublicationProvider">
        <property name="publicationDescriptor" value="org.dd4t.contentmodel.impl.PublicationDescriptorImpl" />
        <property name="cacheProvider" ref="cacheProvider" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="linkResolver" class="org.dd4t.core.resolvers.impl.DefaultLinkResolver"/>
    <bean id="pageFactory" class="org.dd4t.core.factories.impl.PageFactoryImpl"
          factory-method="getInstance">
        <property name="pageProvider" ref="pageProvider" />
        <property name="cacheProvider" ref="cacheProvider" />
        <property name="requestContextClass" value="org.dd4t.core.util.HttpRequestContext" />
        <property name="processors">
            <list>
                <ref bean="linkResolverProcessor" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="componentPresentationFactory" class="org.dd4t.core.factories.impl.ComponentPresentationFactoryImpl" factory-method="getInstance">
        <property name="componentPresentationProvider" ref="componentPresentationProvider" />
        <property name="cacheProvider" ref="cacheProvider" />
        <property name="requestContextClass" value="org.dd4t.core.util.HttpRequestContext" />
        <property name="processors">
            <list>
                <ref bean="linkResolverProcessor" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>    
    <bean id="binaryFactory" class="org.dd4t.core.factories.impl.BinaryFactoryImpl" factory-method="getInstance">
        <property name="binaryProvider" ref="binaryProvider" />
        <property name="cacheProvider" ref="cacheProvider" />
        <property name="requestContextClass" value="org.dd4t.core.util.HttpRequestContext" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="serializer" class="org.dd4t.core.serializers.impl.json.JSONSerializer"/>
    <bean id="serializerFactory" class="org.dd4t.core.serializers.impl.SerializerFactory">
        <constructor-arg name="serializerInstance" ref="serializer"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="taxonomyProvider" class="org.dd4t.providers.impl.BrokerTaxonomyProvider"/>    
    <bean id="taxonomyFactory" class="org.dd4t.core.factories.impl.TaxonomyFactoryImpl" factory-method="getInstance">
        <property name="taxonomyProvider" ref="taxonomyProvider" />
        <property name="cacheProvider" ref="cacheProvider" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="modelConverter" class="org.dd4t.databind.builder.json.JsonModelConverter" />
    <bean id="dataBinder" class="org.dd4t.databind.builder.json.JsonDataBinder" factory-method="getInstance">
        <property name="viewModelPackageRoot" value="${databind.viewmodels.rootpackage}" />
        <property name="viewModelMetaKeyName" value="${databind.viewmodels.ct.metadata.viewnamekey}" />
        <property name="renderDefaultComponentModelsOnly" value="false" />
        <property name="renderDefaultComponentsIfNoModelFound" value="true" />
        <property name="converter" ref="modelConverter" />
        <property name="concreteComponentPresentationImpl" value="org.dd4t.contentmodel.impl.ComponentPresentationImpl" />
        <property name="concreteComponentTemplateImpl" value="org.dd4t.contentmodel.impl.ComponentTemplateImpl" />
        <property name="concreteComponentImpl" value="org.dd4t.contentmodel.impl.ComponentImpl" />
        <property name="concreteFieldImpl" value="org.dd4t.contentmodel.impl.BaseField"/>
    </bean>    
    <bean id="databindFactory" class="org.dd4t.databind.DataBindFactory" factory-method="getInstance">
        <property name="dataBinder" ref="dataBinder" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="xpmRender" class="org.dd4t.mvc.utils.XPMRenderer" factory-method="getInstance">
        <property name="enabled" value="${xpm.enabled}"/>
        <property name="cmsUrl" value="${xpm.cmsUrl}"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Can you try to run it on Tomcat 7 / JDK 7? Are you using Tridion 2013?

Comment: I am trying it on Tomcat8  and in Java 8 environment. I am using SDL Web 8.1.1.

Comment: Can you then update dd4t.version to 2.0.5? An example pom can be found here: https://github.com/dd4t/dd4t-2-java/blob/develop/dd4t-test-spring-web/pom.xml . We actually need to still release the archetype for this version.

Comment: I changed <dd4t.version> to 2.0.5 from 2.0.2. But same Exception persists. @Raimond When would the archetype for this version be released? I mean days, weeks or months.

Comment: Is your namespace "com.example"?

Comment: Which Jar files have been packaged by the build? Do you have dd4t-providers-common-2.0.5.jar and dd4t-providers-web8-2.0.5.jar (or version)

Comment: @ChrisMorgan yes.. my base-package is "com.example"

Comment: yeah i have "dd4t-providers-common-2.0.5.jar" and "dd4t-providers-web8-2.0.5.jar" in my pom.xml file and both jars are present in the final build..

Comment: @Javed - expect next week.

Comment: @Raimond Is there any further update for latest archetype??